# How to install Flash Player Plugin in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, flash, chromium

I am actually using Lubuntu, and I can't install the Abobe Flash Player Plugin with Chromium. When I download it on the Adobe Flash Player website, Lubuntu ask me (in French, sorry, I live in France) : "Chromium doit lancer une application externe pour gérer les liens de type apt:. Le lien demandé est apt:adobe-flashplugin?channel=$distro-parter.
L'application suivante va être lancée si vous acceptée cetet requête : xdg-open
Si vous n'êtes pas à l'origine de cette requête, il s'agit probablement d'une attaque contre votre système. Si vous n'avez pas lancé cette requête de manière intentionnelle, cliquez sur Ne rien faire." Then I click on "Lancer l'application" ("Open the application") and Chromium only open a new page without nothing written (except "Google").
The problem is I can't watch videos on Internet without that plugin.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have some trouble with Flash Player in Ubuntu - Adobe stopped support for Linux about a year ago.  There are several solutions for Chromium, such as using Popper Flash Player, or using Pipelight in wine.  I resorted to using Chrome from Google, as it has a built-in flash player.

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/install-pepper-flash-player-for.html

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html

Comment: Thank you, but when I tried to install google Chrome or pepper flash player, the same message appeared... And Chromium only opened a new page. I think I can't install any packages... That's weird because I have installed Skype before, also using Lubuntu and Chromium, once again. Should I install an another Linux distribution ?

Comment: I think I may have seen the same message long ago when I installed Crhome, but I ignored it and went on to view videos

Comment: I finally installed Chrome, but the deb version :) And I can watch videos ! Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you!  Thanks for the feedback.